# is managedobject.managedobjectcontext dfifferent from that shared in appdelegate

Tags: nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, appdelegate

I'm confused. Sometimes I use self.managedObjectContext in managedObject.m is just fine, however, now I got strange errors such as cocoa error 1550 or different contexts.